# vtiger: add description field in quick create event form

Tags: vtiger

How can I add the description field in the quick create event form? I tried to find the field in the *vtiger_field* table, but there is no such field. However, there is a column called quickcreate.

Also the layout editor (under settings) does not allow me to edit the fields of the events module.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put to 0 or 2 the column quickcreate of the vtiger_field.
Pay attention to the tabid column, 9 is for Todos and 16 for Events